# Best dialog for the job?

Tags: android

**Which dialog is best for this?**

1) For asking user input for new name for a folder? Single text field and OK/cancel bottons.

2) Asking user input for modifying size of multiple files? Single text field, few seekbars, OK/cancel buttons.

3) Just displaying properties of a file with multiple colors.

It would be best if I could do this within a single activity, and I'm calling these dialings via context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [`AlertDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) with a custom `View` layout for its content will probably be sufficient.

Comment: @BinoyBabu There are many tutorials out there for this. For example http://www.androiddom.com/2011/06/displaying-android-pop-up-dialog_13.html

Comment: Can you help me out with this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447565/set-title-of-context-menu-from-the-selected-listview-item