# Set title of context menu from the selected Listview item

Tags: android

How can I set title of the context menu from the selected `Listview` item? This below is my **main activity**.

```
public class OListActivity extends ListActivity {
......
......
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        ......
......
        MatrixCursor cursor;
        cursor = NameManager.getnameList();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        String[] from = { "name", "info", "status", BaseColumns._ID };
        int[] to = { R.id.name, R.id.info, R.id.status };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Menu");// TODO Change to name of selected listview item.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }
.....
.....
```

I need to set `menu.setHeaderTitle` to `R.id.name`. I'm aware of another similer [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2321332/1068546) but it don't mention about dealing with a complex `ListView` with multiple textviews.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `ContextMenuInfo` parameter from the `onCreateContextMenu()` method:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
        try {
            // Casts the incoming data object into the type for AdapterView objects.
            info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // If the menu object can't be cast, logs an error.
            Log.e(TAG, "bad menuInfo", e);
            return;
        }
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
        if (cursor == null) {
            // For some reason the requested item isn't available, do nothing
            return;
        }

        // if your column name is "name"
        menu.setHeaderTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. By the way I had to change to `menu.setHeaderTitle(cursor.getString(1))`.

Comment: @BinoyBabu You are right the method `getString()` requires an `int` and not a `String`. I'm tired and i was thinking to the method `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));`.

Comment: Don't worry about it. You are my hero anyway. Get some sleep okay?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old post and is the correct answer as well. However, while using this today I came across something I will like to add.

The `ContextMenuInfo` parameter is used to find the exact item position which initiated the ContextMenu i.e our adpater item.

Hence, it can return an item of type defined in the Adapter's `getItem()` method using that position `info.position`, as in the above the getItem() method returns a **Cursor** object.

(In my case it returned a Model class and then I realized that to set the Title via `menu.setHeaderTitle()` I can pass my methods that my model supports like `model.getItamName()`)

Also, remember if your AdapterView contains any header you will have to exclude them while fetching the position using menuInfo. Like,

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position - yourList.getHeaderViewsCount());
```

Hope this helps someone. :)